# Dolphin - Not possible to enter folder XYZ

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I'm trying to simply copy a folder from a disk to another disk. When doing the copy paste Dolphin (I'm using KDE) is bombarding me with thousands of messages "Unable to enter folder XYZ" (translation may be different. My actual message is "No se ha podido entrar en la carpeta /media/...").

I don't want to fix the folder: the disk is having issues and I'm rescuing data. But I don't want to click "ok" thousands times. It can be changed or configured somehow?

Comment: What exact command did you give to produce the errors?  $PATH is typically not a folder, but a list of folders, so is inappropriate in a cp command.

Comment: Right click in a folder, copy, right click on destination folder, paste. No, I didn't use $PATH, just forgot that it was a well known environment variable.

Comment: Have you tried using `cp -R 'XYZ folder' 'destination folder'` in a terminal window?

Comment: The question is about dolphin GUI showing the same error hundreds of times, not about other commands for copying. I'm aware of cp, rsync and other file managers.